How to start KDE automatically on Alma Linux (CentOS / RHEL)?
After installing Alma Linux 8 with the Server configuration (not the Server With GUI configuration, which uses Gnome) and following Alma Docs > After-installation Guide, KDE does not start automatically and requires startx to be run.
How can KDE be started automatically?

The following commands aren't mentioned in that doc but are required:
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
sudo systemctl enable graphical.target --force
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service
reboot

KDE will now start automatically.
Combined from 2 answers at:

Startx not automatically running on reboot
Reached graphical.target, but still have to type startx to start gui

